# Validate text for multiple text boxes?

Tags: c#

I have a WinForm(c#) that has 10 Text boxes inside a Group box

The user should only be allowed to enter numbers 1 to 100:
-- All of the Text boxes are in one GroupBox -- if it helps

How do I apply the below mentioned code to multiple text Boxes?

```
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
     int i;
     if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out i))
     {
      if (i >= 0 && i <= 100)
      return;
     }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number from 1 - 100");
```

[image]
Upon clicking "add" if the user typed in a number above 100 or nothing it should  pop up a warning window

Comment: Have you looked at the [Control.Leave Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=netframework-4.8) ? Bear in mind, that you should DO SOMETHING if the value is bad, like set the text box text to an empty string, otherwise, the error will KEEP POPPING up until the user enters a valid value.

Comment: Have you considered deriving your own control from `TextBox`? Then you can restrict user input to integers via keydown. You can simultaneously check what the resultant value will be, and if it surpasses Max (which you can add as Property) reject the value entered, together with a popup message. I also recommend adding a Value property. Your add event would then require no validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each control in the GroupBox, and check which ones are textboxes:

```
ForEach (Control tb in gb.Controls) //gb is a reference your GroupBox object
{
  if tb is TextBox
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out i))
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i <= 100)
            return;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number from 1 - 100");
}
```

In the absence of more context as to what you are doing, it would be hard to optimise your validation process, but this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

With complex forms `MessageBox.Show` may become rather annoying:

- it does not point the user to the incorrect field
- it shows errors one-by-one, you may have many more incorrect inputs

Also proposed approach 'allows' user to fail by clicking on the 'Add' button.

I'd recommend using [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=netframework-4.8) to point the user to the failed inputs and disable button if the model (in your case - all inputs) is invalid. You may even restrict the user to do not leave a field if it provides a wrong input :)

You may read a guide for [User Input Validation in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/user-input-validation-in-windows-forms), it gives an overview of validation instrumentation in WindowsForms.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private HashSet<TextBox> validatedInputs = new HashSet<TextBox>();
        private int inputsCount;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Enabled = false;
            foreach (var tb in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                tb.Validating += allTextBoxs_ValidatingAndEditing;
                tb.TextChanged += allTextBoxs_ValidatingAndEditing;
                inputsCount++;
            }
        }

        private void allTextBoxs_ValidatingAndEditing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is TextBox tb)
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(tb.Text, out int value) || value < 0 || value > 100)
                {
                    if (e is CancelEventArgs ce)
                        ce.Cancel = true;
                    errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "Value must be in range [0..100]");
                    validatedInputs.Remove(tb);
                }
                else
                {
                    errorProvider1.SetError(tb, null);
                    validatedInputs.Add(tb);
                }

                setAddButtonEnabled();
            }
        }

        private void setAddButtonEnabled() => button1.Enabled = validatedInputs.Count == inputsCount;
    }
```

[image: FormValidation]

Be careful, this implementation is so restrictive that user even cannot close a form until he types a right value :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using the text box’s leave event. In addition, the text boxes key press event is used to allow only numbers. Wire-up each text boxes `Leave` and `KeyPress` event to the one below and it should work as you describe. As others have mention there are numerous ways to do this.

```
private void tb_Course_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
  if (tb.Text == "")
    return;
  if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out int value)) {
    if (value >= 0 && value <= 100) {
      return;
    }
  }
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter a VALID number from 1 - 100");
  tb.Text = "";
}


private void tb_Course_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a method for Leave events and set this method to leave event of each text box in the properties window:

```
private void TextBoxGroup_Leave(object sender, TextBox e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(e.Text) > 100)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number from 1 - 100");
        e.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to validate the input of your textboxes across multiple group boxes you can try this.

```
 private void ValidateInputOfControls(Control.ControlCollection[] controlsArray)
    {          
        foreach (Control.ControlCollection controlCollection in controlsArray)
        {
            foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
            {
                if (control is TextBox)
                {
                    int result;
                    if (int.TryParse(control.Text, out result))
                    {
                        if (!(result >= 0 && result <= 100))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number from 1 - 100 in field " + control.Name);

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number from 1 - 100 in field " + control.Name);
                    }
                 }
            }               
        }
    }
```

All you need to do is to Add the controls of your group boxes in a Control.ControlCollection array and then call the method. See example below.

```
Control.ControlCollection[] controls = { groupBox1.Controls, groupBox2.Controls };
ValidateInputOfControls(controls);
```